# Does it matter if I don't explicitly cast time_t argument to unsigned int argument when using srand with time?

Tags: c++

When using time to initialize srand, should I explicitly cast the time_t return value of time to an unsigned int, or just pass it directly to srand?

I.e. Should I do this:

`srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)))`

or just

`srand(time(0))`?

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) is a `typedef` for an implementation specific (almost always) integral type. Since [`srand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) takes an `unsigned int` argument, and any integral type is implicitly convertible to `unsigned int`, you get exactly the same behavior with or without the explicit `static_cast<unsigned int>`.

If you have c++11 available, I would strongly suggest using the facilities provided in the [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) header for any serious random number generation. For a thorough discussion of this, I suggest [watching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DPkyvkMkk8) Walter Brown's talk at CppCon 2016.

Comment: Compiler flags related to *warnings* may prevent some integral types from implicitly converting to `unsigned int`.  That would favor one of the approaches more.

Comment: `time_t` is "real" type, meaning it can be either integer (signed or unsigned) or floating-point. You're right about the conversion, though, a cast will make no difference (and can be error-prone, since you have to get the target type right). In the unlikely event that it's a floating-point type, and that the value is negative or exceeds `UINT_MAX`, the conversion can have undefined behavior. I don't know of any implementation where that would be a problem, and `srand(time(NULL))` is a common idiom that implementers wouldn't want to break.

Comment: @KeithThompson In the event that it is a floating-point type with a value that is negative or exceeds `UINT_MAX`, would the undefined behavior apply to both the implicit and explicit conversions?

Comment: @DanielGilbert: Yes. Conversion of a signed or unsigned integer to an unsigned type wraps around. In all other numeric conversions (excluding `bool`), the behavior is undefined if the value is outside the range of the target type. Explicit and implicit conversions behave the same way.